# Image combination alignment

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

```mathematica
homoLumoLines[homoY_] := 
 Graphics[{(*HOMO直线*){Thick, 
    Line[{{0, homoY}, {2, homoY}}]},(*LUMO指向HOMO的箭头*){Thick, 
    Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, homoY}}]},(*LUMO直线*){Thick, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]

(*创建包含HOMO和LUMO文字的Graphics对象*)
homoLumoText := 
 Graphics[{(*HOMO文字*){Text[
     Style["HOMO", FontSize -> 14], {0, 1}]},(*LUMO文字*){Text[
     Style["LUMO", FontSize -> 14], {0, 0}]}}, ImageSize -> {50, 100}]

(*假设的3D图形*)
s0HomoGra3D := 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]
s0LumoGra3D := Graphics3D[{Cuboid[]}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]

(*使用Row和Column组合所有图形*)
Row[{homoLumoText, 
  Column[{s0HomoGra3D, homoLumoLines[1], s0LumoGra3D}, Spacings -> 0]}]
```

[image]

I created this image, but it is not what I wanted; I want the following effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
homoLumoLines[homoY_] := 
 Graphics[{(*HOMO*){Thick, Line[{{0, homoY}, {2, homoY}}], 
    Text[Style["HOMO", FontSize -> 12], {2.5, 
      0.95 homoY}]},(*LUMOHOMO*){Thick, Arrowheads[0.1], 
    Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, homoY}}]},(*LUMO*){Thick, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], 
    Text[Style["LUMO", FontSize -> 12], {2.5, 0.05}]}}, 
  ImageSize -> {200, 100}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-0.2, 1.2 homoY}}]
homoLumoLines[1]

s0HomoGra3D = 
  Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}];
s0LumoGra3D = Graphics3D[{Cuboid[]}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}];


GP = GraphicsColumn[{s0HomoGra3D, homoLumoLines[1], s0LumoGra3D}, 
  Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

### **To get the green boxes**

```
 homoLumoLines[homoY_] := 
 Graphics[{(*HOMO*){{Thick, Line[{{0, homoY}, {2, homoY}}], 
     Text[Style["HOMO", FontSize -> 14, Bold], {-0.3, 
       0.99 homoY}]},(*LUMOHOMO*){Thick, Arrowheads[0.05], 
     Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, homoY}}]},(*LUMO*){Thick, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], 
     Text[Style["LUMO", FontSize -> 14, Bold], {-0.3, 
       0.01}]}}, {EdgeForm[Directive[Green, Thick]], FaceForm[None], 
    Rectangle[{-0.6, -0.1}, {2.8, 0.1 homoY}], 
    Rectangle[{-0.6, 0.9 homoY}, {2.8, 1.1 homoY}]}}, 
  ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-0.2, 1.2 homoY}}]
homoLumoLines[1]
```

[image]

I am unable to add the red box.